# Datetime difference to return Days only?

Tags: python, regex, datetime

```
$ cat .t.py 
import re
from datetime import datetime as dtt

oldestDate = dateComp = dtt.strptime('1.1.1001', '%d.%m.%Y')
dateComp = dtt.strptime('11.1.2011', '%d.%m.%Y')
ind = re.sub(" days,.*", "", str((dateComp - oldestDate)))

print ind
print dateComp - oldestDate
$ python .t.py 
368905
368905 days, 0:00:00
```

How can I get days only without the regex code-smell? The problem escalate because I need to use the index in many locations. So some cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `str()` so soon. The result you get back from subtracting one `datetime` from another is a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object, which has a `.days` property that you can read.

```
(dateComp - oldestDate).days
```

Note that reading *only* the `.days` property will mean that it will round down the difference - if you instead want to round to the nearest number of days, you'll need to add some logic to check the `.seconds` property to see whether it's closer to 0 or 86400.